# Joining datatables to create a new datatable

Tags: c#, performance, linq, .net-datatable

I am joining datatables to create a new datatable:

```
var row = from r0w1 in dt_vi.AsEnumerable()
              join r0w2 in dt_w.AsEnumerable()
              on r0w1.Field<int>("ID") equals r0w2.Field<int>("iD")
              join r0w3 in dt_re.AsEnumerable()
              on r0w1.Field<int?>("ID") equals r0w3.Field<int?>("id")
              join r0w4 in dt_def.AsEnumerable()
              on r0w1.Field<int?>("ID") equals r0w4.Field<int?>("id") into ps
              from r0w4 in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select r0w1.ItemArray.Concat(r0w2.ItemArray.Concat(r0w3.ItemArray.Concat(r0w4 != null ? r0w4.ItemArray : new object[] { }))).ToArray();


foreach (object[] values in row)
    dt.Rows.Add(values);
```

In the above code,

```
foreach (object[] values in row)
    dt.Rows.Add(values);
```

is slow for lakhs of rows. I want to put the data of `row` into `dt` datatable. Is there any faster way of doing this?

Comment: What is "lakhs"? Do you mean "lots"?

Comment: 100000 = 1 Lakh. Indians use this unit. I dont know if it is used elsewhere in the world or not.

Comment: Could you show your Domain Models?

Comment: because of joins , more joins in a query always effecting the performance better to create master table to get the data or use weak entity set, could you show your model it will give more clear picture

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to run some tests (I was very curious about LINQ on objects vs. SQL processing performance):

**1) Setup**

```
-- drop table t1
create table t1 (id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, name NVARCHAR(1000))
go
-- drop table t2
create table t2 (id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, name NVARCHAR(1000))
go
-- drop table t3
create table t3 (id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, name NVARCHAR(1000))
go
-- drop table t4
create table t4 (id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, name NVARCHAR(1000))
go

insert into t1 select top 200000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), CAST(text AS NVARCHAR(1000)) from sys.messages
insert into t2 select top 200000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), CAST(text AS NVARCHAR(1000)) from sys.messages where message_id > 1000
insert into t3 select top 200000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), CAST(text AS NVARCHAR(1000)) from sys.messages where message_id > 2000
insert into t4 select top 200000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), CAST(text AS NVARCHAR(1000)) from sys.messages where message_id > 3000
```

All tables have 2 Lakhs (200K)

Application and SQL run on the same machine (PC).

**2) C# code**

```
        public static DataTable fillDataTable(SqlConnection sqlConn, string table)
        {
            return fillDataTableByQuery(sqlConn, "SELECT * FROM " + table);
        }

        public static DataTable fillDataTableByQuery(SqlConnection sqlConn, String query)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(dt);
            }

            return dt;
        }

            var dt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++ )
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(String.Format("Id{0}", i), typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add(String.Format("Name{0}", i), typeof(String));
            }

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();

                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();

                var dt1 = fillDataTable(con, "t1");
                var dt2 = fillDataTable(con, "t2");
                var dt3 = fillDataTable(con, "t3");
                var dt4 = fillDataTable(con, "t4");
                Console.WriteLine("Loaded in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                sw.Reset(); sw.Start();

                var row = from r0w1 in dt1.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
                          join r0w2 in dt2.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
                            on r0w1.Field<int>("ID") equals r0w2.Field<int>("iD")
                          join r0w3 in dt3.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
                            on r0w1.Field<int?>("ID") equals r0w3.Field<int?>("id")
                          join r0w4 in dt4.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
                            on r0w1.Field<int?>("ID") equals r0w4.Field<int?>("id") into ps
                            from r0w4 in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select r0w1.ItemArray.Concat(r0w2.ItemArray.Concat(r0w3.ItemArray.Concat(r0w4 != null ? r0w4.ItemArray : new object[] { }))).ToArray();

                foreach (object[] values in row)
                    dt.Rows.Add(values);

                Console.WriteLine("Processed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                sw.Reset(); sw.Start();

                var directDt = fillDataTableByQuery(con, @"
select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*, t4.*
from t1
    join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
    join t3 on t3.id = t2.id
    left join t4 on t4.id = t3.id
");

                Console.WriteLine("Sql process + fetch in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

**3) Results**

**No parallel**

```
Loaded in 4370
Processed in 3249
Sql process + fetch in 3033
```

**With parallel**

```
Loaded in 4240
Processed in 1904
Sql process + fetch in 3160
```

So, including fetch, SQL performs better in this case (IDs are all clustered indexes). Also, using AsParallel makes a difference, at least on my machine (eight-core).

**[later edit] - Dictionary version**

Since you have to deal with fwk. 3.5. (VS 2008) and you said that you load data once and do more processing, I think you can try out the following:

```
    class AggrData
    {
        public int Id1 { get; set; }
        public String Name1 { get; set; }
        public int Id2 { get; set; }
        public String Name2 { get; set; }
        public int Id3 { get; set; }
        public String Name3 { get; set; }
        public int Id4 { get; set; }
        public String Name4 { get; set; }
    }

    // value is defined as anonymous type for extensibility
    var dict1 = dt1.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(r => r.Field<int>("ID"), r => new { Name = r.Field<String>("Name") });
    var dict2 = dt2.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(r => r.Field<int>("ID"), r => new { Name = r.Field<String>("Name") });
    var dict3 = dt3.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(r => r.Field<int>("ID"), r => new { Name = r.Field<String>("Name") });
    var dict4 = dt4.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(r => r.Field<int>("ID"), r => new { Name = r.Field<String>("Name") });

    Console.WriteLine("Dictionary setup took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Reset(); sw.Start();

    var aggrList = new List<AggrData>();
    foreach (var key in dict1.Keys)
    {
        if (!dict2.ContainsKey(key) || !dict3.ContainsKey(key))
            continue;

        var newAggr = new AggrData() 
            {   Id1 = key, Name1 = dict1[key].Name, 
                Id2 = key, Name2 = dict2[key].Name,
                Id3 = key, Name3 = dict3[key].Name
            };
        if (dict4.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            newAggr.Id4 = key;
            newAggr.Name3 = dict4[key].Name;
        }

        aggrList.Add(newAggr);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Aggregate POCOs fill took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Reset(); sw.Start();
```

**Results:**

```
Dictionary setup took 3654
Aggregate POCOs fill took 202
```

So, setup is expensive, but the actual fill is much faster, as checking and retrieving data from Dictionary is very fast - O(1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I do calculations or perform queries then it takes much CPU f the server. Also, I use this above taken data from the datatable at various place, which prevents from every time visiting to the database.

Comment: Then your path is clear. You just add AsParallel to your IEnumerables and leave the logic in C#. Another option is to try using Dictionary<int, SomeClassHoldingTheData> for data tables used in joins, so that id match is done faster (I will give it a try once I have some spare time).

Comment: I am getting an error when I am using `AsParallel()`. `does not contain a definition for 'AsParallel'`. How did you ran it ? I am using visual studio 2008.

Comment: I am using VS2013 Community here. AsParallel() is part of PLINQ - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(v=vs.100).aspx - and it is available from .NET Fwk 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010+).

Comment: May be that's why it is not working for me since I am using VS 2008 with 3.5 framework. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Forgot to add a comment after posting the edit. I have added an option using Dictionary<> that is supported in 3.5.

Comment: Thanks @Alexei, for your reply. As I am seeing your edited question, do I have to create separate dictionary for every datatable column i.e. `q.cID, q.status, q.defectID, q.name, q.description, q.dftAID, q.dftName`? I have edited my question to add some more details.

Comment: No, the dictionary can have a value that has multiple properties. E.g.: r => new { Name = r.Field<String>("Name"), DefectId = f.Field<int>("defectId"), other properties in anonymous type come here }.